# asp.net user permissions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, permissions

I am quite confused about this and none of the texts / docs / SO questions have elucidated the matter for me.

I want my asp.net MVC app to be able to save an XML doc to a folder on the server. But I am getting an exception...

```
Access to the path 'D:\blah\blah\folder\xml_data.xml' is denied.
```

So as I understand it my application is running under a user account that does not have write permissions.

I think I had this problem before and my solution was to contact my web host and ask them to give my site permissions.

But what if I want to create my own custom set of roles with corressponding permissions? Do these have to be added into IIS? Would I have to create a list and then hand it over the the web host? What would such a list look like? As I understand it, it is not possible to configure roles and permissions in web.config, is that correct?

Once I have the roles and their permissions set up how to I set the default role for the app to run under and also how do I programitically change the role that the app is running under?

ps. I don't want to use asp.net membership I would like to know how to set this up myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asp.net membership.  I don't care if you don't like it.  Use it.  It's easy, it's simple, and it gets security right.  You will mess security up if you do it yourself and don't know what you're doing.

People give membership a bad rap, it's a good tool.  Most people just make the wrong assumptions about it.

You define your roles in the membership/role API.  This is stored in your database.  You can't have roles without a user to apply them to, so you need a membership system of some type.

EDIT:

There are two kinds of users here.  The first is the user that the ASP.NET worker process runs as under IIS.  This is the user that your host must define, and allow to access various folders to access files.

The second is the IIdentity user of asp.net, this is the user that asp.net defines for the logged in web user, and this is completely seperate from the Worker process user.  IIdentity users have no inherent operating system rights or privileges, other than those assigned to the worker process identity.

In other words, IIDentity based users run as the same Worker process identity in IIS.

The exception to this is when you define "impersonate=true" in the web.config, and this allows the worker process to "log on" to the OS as the user in question.  In other words, the worker process will run as the web users credentials.  This requires that the web user have credentials in the OS as well.

The other exception is that you can specify a specific OS user to impersonate in the web.config.  But, again, there must be an operating system user to impersonate.  Also, impersonation is a very expensive operation and takes a lot of system resources.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I asked specifically to know how to do this without asp.net membership. I know I can progamatically set the Principal, Identity and Roles. I need to know how to create my custom roles and permissions. Do I have to define them and ask the host to set them up or can I set them up myself? This is all I am interested in. Thank you.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 - Principal, Identity, and Roles have nothing to do with the Windows user that the process runs under (which is the problem you were describing with accessing the files). You don't have to have the host know anything about them, they're completely defined in your code and in the database. Your IPrincipal and IIDentity objects control everything. If your users need to access files, then you still have to have the web process run as an identity that Windows gives permission to. There is the concept known as Impersonation, but that only applies if the users have accounts on server.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 - I still recommend using Membership api if you don't fully understand the way in which IPrincipal and IIDentity work (which your questions lead me to believe you don't, or you would know the answers to the questions).  I suggest reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649100.aspx

Comment: So should I just ask my host to give the site full permissions and control who can do what programatically? As I understood it the user that the process runs under should change depending on who is logged on. It says in the texts/docs I have read that a site should be configured to run under minimal privillages. But obviously some users will need more privillages so for them the process will need to run in the context of a different user. my site will use something similar to forms authentication not windows authentication. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 - that's probably best.  Two other options are to store files in your database, or to create OS users for the web users.  Your host will probalby not like the latter, and depending on how large the files are storing them in the db may not be viable.  Just understand that if an attacker gains access to your site through some vulnerability then they can access all files the worker process can access.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification between the OS user the worker process runs under and website user. Should I then ask the web host to create several worker process users with different permissions? A default for ordinary users of the website, then various admin users for different levels of admin? Then when a senior admin is logged on to the site the worker process could impersonate this admin. Would this give extra worthwhile security? Or would this cause extra overhead of all users trying to be impersonated?

Comment: I take it a OS user would have to be created for each site user. I can't create an OS user group and then say this user belongs to such a group?

Comment: Maybe the correct solution is to set up a worker process user that has full permission for only one folder - the App_Data folder?

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 - You can't really say that some users will be impersonated, and some won't.. Well you can.. but it's a more drawn out process.  During the login phase, you have to use the Windows API LoginUser.  All this may be moot anyways, since impersonation and using LoginUser require that hosting be setup as Full Trust, and most shared hosting won't allow that.  A VPS (VIrtual Private Server) should, and of course a dedicated server would.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 - Yes, one worker process with access to App_Data is probably the best solution overall.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You have clarified this a lot for me. Someone else gave your answer a -1 so I gave it a +1 to counter it!